# One ajax script for multiple inputs/buttons?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I'm loading a `<div>` (using JSON results) to list videos hosted on my Wistia account. Each video has a `hashed_id` associated with it. I'm looking for a solution to `POST` a `DELETE` request to the Wistia API to remove the video. To do that, I need to pass the video's `hashed_id` to my PHP script.

I can't think of way to do this, without writing an ajax function for each video... any help?

Here's a simplified version of my HTML:

```
<div>
 <h1>Video Title1</h2>
 <input type="hidden" value="as958ssf3h">
 <button>Delete</button>
</div>
<div>
 <h1>Video Title2</h2>
 <input type="hidden" value="aasdflkj39">
 <button>Delete</button>
</div>
<div>
 <h1>Video Title3</h2>
 <input type="hidden" value="asdfsdf933">
 <button>Delete</button>
</div>
```

And my javascript (jquery):

```
$("button").click(function(){
 $.ajax({
  url: "demo_test.php",
  data: $("input").val(),
  type: "POST",
 }});
});
```

Comment: syntax errors........? use proper syntactical code which you tried.

Comment: here is some help remove ; from ` $("input").val();,`

Comment: @madalinivascu, fixed.. heh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 var token = "wistia aplication token"
    $("button").click(function(){
     $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.wistia.com/v1/medias/"+$(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val()+".json?api_password="+token,
      data:{_method:"DELETE"},
      type: "POST",
      success:function(data){
        alert(data.name+"has been deleted")
     }
    });
    });
```

see more about the api at :http://wistia.com/doc/data-api

Comment: Don't I need to run a PHP command to delete a video? Or can it be done only using Javascript?

Comment: you can do it with only js, you need the wistia api token

Comment: I have a working PHP script that does it (hence my Posting to a php file question), but this is way easier! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What about
data: { id: $('input[type=hidden]', this.closest("div")).val(); }